# How to add start and end coordinate to attributes of a road network?

Tags: arcpy, coordinates, network-analyst, network-dataset

I have generated a road network from open street map data. How can i add start and end coordinates (point_x, point_y) to its attributes table via toolbox or arcpy? 
[image]
That's how the roads look like. 
I also have the shapefile, but i believe this should be more appropriate, since the junctions i need are already identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the field calculator. If you have a field (like `start_x`), use the field calculator with the expression `!SHAPE!.firstPoint.X`, and for a field like `end_x` you would use `!SHAPE!.lastPoint.X`. for your Y coordinates, you would use `!SHAPE!.firstPoint.Y` and `!SHAPE!.lastPoint.Y`

Check out the arcpy geometry documentation(http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm). firstPoint and lastPoint return Point objects, which you can read about here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/point.htm

EDIT: you have to use the Python parser, at the top of the field calculator window

Comment: +1. It is useful to know manual things, I do it often. However add geometry tool does it on the fly and also creates fields required

Comment: thank you for the answer and also for the links, but my problem is flied calculator is grayed out while using road network. it is on when working with the shapefile, however, shapefile doesn't have the break points i need.

Comment: so even the "Calculate Field" tool in the arcmap data management toolbox doesn't work? (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm)

Comment: Also found this on adding attributes to a network (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/editing-network-datasets-modifying-network-attributes.htm), and this tool for calculating locations on a network (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/calculate-locations.htm)

Comment: If you calculate the start/end points on your shapefile you might be able to make XY event layers for both and add those locations to your network

Comment: sorry for replying late, cause i used to get emails for each response, apparently i dont any more. afte your first solution i browsed through "Fundamentals of field calculations" and found this: "You are not in an edit session and you need to be editing to calculate the data. For example, you must be in an edit session when working with versioned ArcSDE data or a feature class that participates in a geodatabase topology, a geometric network, or a relationship class" and the problem was solved. Thank you again.